Plot is not saved in R (white image)
I have a lot of code to perform some bioinformatics analyis and at some point I need to save some plots. I cannot use ggsave because of the package I am making the plot with. I tried to create a minum reproducible example but I can't understand what causes it. What i know is that sometimes does not work.
Some examples:
(https://github.com/kevinblighe/CorLevelPlot) this package and this function:
      png(file=paste0(output_dir, "mri_correlation_heatmap.png"))
      CorLevelPlot(heatmap.data,
                   x = names(heatmap.data)[(length(heatmap.data)-2):length(heatmap.data)],
                   y = names(heatmap.data)[1:(length(heatmap.data)-9)],
                   col = c("blue1", "skyblue", "white", "pink", "red"))
      dev.off()

or this (https://github.com/jinworks/CellChat?tab=readme-ov-file)
png(file=paste0(output_dir, name, ".png"))
netAnalysis_contribution(cellchat, signaling = pathways.show)
dev.off()

I know this is not ver helpful in the way that a lot of information is missing, but the point is: this code works, but only when I debug it one line at a time, if I run it withut debugging, it saves a white image. I cannot understand how to try to solve it.

Welcome to SO.  I think you should be careful here: the online doc reads, in part "The format of recorded plots may change between R versions, so recorded plots should not be used as a permanent storage format for R plots" and "As of R 3.3.0, it is possible (again) to replay a plot from another R session using, for example, saveRDS and readRDS. It is even possible to replay a plot from another R version, however, this will produce warnings, may produce errors, or something worse".

Thank you for your reply. Actually, this time this part is not true, it is some time that I am strugling with this as I have not control over the output of the functions that I use for plotting, and last time the object was of that class. This time functions output for example a heatmap (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ComplexHeatmap/versions/1.10.2/topics/Heatmap) class object. It happens when I use this method of directing the output of a grapic device. (png() and dev.off())

I would suggest making a minimal reproducible example and maybe also including your session info, or at least the R version and OS
